# How to recursively compare two Codable objects and get differences in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have two instances of `Lecture` which are  `oldLecture` and `newLecture`. A simplified declaration of `Lecture` is as follows (the full version has many more fields):

```swift
struct Lecture: Codable {
    let title: String
    let class_times: [ClassTime]
    let color: [String: String]
}

struct ClassTime: Codable {
    let start: Double
    let len: Double
}
```

Now I need to *recursively* compare `oldLecture` and `newLecture`, and create a new dictionary-like object that contains *only* the properties that are modified in `newLecture`. The resulting object will be sent to the server as `PUT` request.

For example,

```swift
var oldLecture = Lecture(title: "lecture1", 
                         class_times: [ClassTime(start: 1, len: 2)], 
                         color: ["fg": "#fff", "bg": "#000"])
var newLecture = Lecture(title: "lecture1", 
                         class_times: [ClassTime(start: 2, len: 3)], 
                         color: ["fg": "#fff", "bg": "#000"])

// the result object should only contain `class_times` key with the value of `[ClassTime(start: 2, len: 3)]`
```

### What I have tried so far

```swift
guard let oldDict = oldLecture.asDictionary() else { return nil }
guard let newDict = newLecture.asDictionary() else { return nil }
var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
for (key, newVal) in newDict {
    if let oldVal = oldDict[key], oldVal != newVal {
        dict[key] = newVal
    }
}
```

The approach above won't work because it doesn't compare `oldVal` and `newVal` recursively.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this, without using third-party libraries such as `SwiftyJSON`?

Comment: What does *recursively* mean?

Comment: @vadian I meant deep comparison when there are nested dictionaries, etc. In the example above, I need to compare the **content** of `ClassTime` objects, not just the references to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to look into [Sets and Set Arithmetics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set).
This code is probably not fully what you want, but it should point you in the right direction.

By creating a symetric different set of the times of both lectures we get a list of times that are in either lecture, but not both.

```
struct Lecture: Codable, Equatable {
    let title: String
    let times: [LectureTime]
    let color: [String: String]
}

struct LectureTime: Codable, Hashable {
    let start: Double
    let len: Double
}

var oldLecture = Lecture(title: "lecture1",
                         times: [.init(start: 1, len: 2), .init(start: 5, len: 2)],
                         color: ["fg": "#fff", "bg": "#000"])
var newLecture = Lecture(title: "lecture1",
                         times: [.init(start: 2, len: 3), .init(start: 5, len: 2)],
                         color: ["fg": "#fff", "bg": "#000"])


if oldLecture != newLecture {
    let oldTimes = Set(oldLecture.times)
    let newTimes = Set(newLecture.times)
    let x = oldTimes.symmetricDifference(newTimes)
    print(String(describing:x))
}
```

prints

```
[LectureTime(start: 1.0, len: 2.0), LectureTime(start: 2.0, len: 3.0)]
```

Probably you want to extend your time model to be identifiable—  than you could identify, what time has been changed.

Answer (score -1):

to get the all the differences between the newLecture and  oldLecture (or vice versa),
and send that to your server, try this approach, using `Equatable` for `ClassTime`, that will compare the content of `ClassTime` objects.
The results of `getDiff(...)` gives you a `Lecture`, with the title differences in the `title` field, and similarly for `color` and `class_times` fields.

```
 let result = getDiff(old: oldLecture, new: newLecture)
 print("\n---> result: \(result)")
 do {
     let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(result)
     print("---> data: \(data)")
     // --> send data to your server
     if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
         print("---> this is the json object you are sending: \(str)")
     }
 } catch {
     print("---> error: \(error)")
 }
 
 where:
 
 func getDiff(old: Lecture, new: Lecture) -> Lecture {
     let title = old.title == new.title ? "" : new.title
     let color: [String: String] = new.color.filter{ dic in
         !old.color.contains(where: { $0.key == dic.key && $0.value == dic.value })
     }
     let cls = new.class_times.filter{ !old.class_times.contains($0)}
     return Lecture(title: title, class_times: cls, color: color)
 }
```

with:

```
 struct ClassTime: Codable, Equatable {  // <-- here
     let start: Double
     let len: Double
 }
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you? Works very well for me.